# How to access Ubuntu 22.04 with fastbios and nvidia 510 drivers

Tags: command-line, nvidia, 22.04, bios, nvidia-geforce

Trying to fix a stuttering error with 515 NVIDIA drivers, I reverted back to 510. That causes me a black screen and I can't login. I also have fast-bios enabled, meaning I can't access BIOS either. Keyboard is responding however. Is there any command to disable graphics and access the terminal?

Comment: The grub menu has a firmware option, select it and turn off fast boot.  A virtual term is avail with the key combination ctrl+alt+F3  .A previous kernel selection under the grub "Advanced" menu should allow you back in.

Comment: Great, this worked for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grub menu has a firmware option, select it and turn off fast boot.
A virtual term is available with the key combination ctrl+alt+F3 .
A previous kernel selection under the grub "Advanced" menu should allow you back in.